# Talend Open Studio - an error (sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain))

Tags: java, etl, talend, java-11, java-16

For first launch Talend Open Studio have an error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2613)
    at org.apache.webbeans.proxy.Unsafe.lambda$unsafeDefineClass$2(Unsafe.java:163)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at org.apache.webbeans.proxy.Unsafe.unsafeDefineClass(Unsafe.java:160)
    at org.apache.webbeans.proxy.Unsafe.defineAndLoadClass(Unsafe.java:126)
    at org.apache.webbeans.proxy.AbstractProxyFactory.createProxyClass(AbstractProxyFactory.java:280)
    at org.apache.webbeans.proxy.AbstractProxyFactory.createProxyClass(AbstractProxyFactory.java:250)
    at org.apache.webbeans.proxy.InterceptorDecoratorProxyFactory.createProxyClass(InterceptorDecoratorProxyFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.webbeans.proxy.InterceptorDecoratorProxyFactory.createProxyClass(InterceptorDecoratorProxyFactory.java:188)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.AbstractProducer.defineInterceptorStack(AbstractProducer.java:105)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validate(BeansDeployer.java:1183)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints(BeansDeployer.java:1104)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:330)
    at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.bootstrapApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:137)
    at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:103)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:98)
    at org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener.doStart(WebBeansConfigurationListener.java:207)
    at org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener.contextInitialized(WebBeansConfigurationListener.java:85)
    at org.apache.meecrowave.openwebbeans.OWBAutoSetup$EagerBootListener.doContextInitialized(OWBAutoSetup.java:84)
    at org.apache.meecrowave.openwebbeans.OWBAutoSetup$EagerBootListener.access$100(OWBAutoSetup.java:65)
    at org.apache.meecrowave.openwebbeans.OWBAutoSetup.onStartup(OWBAutoSetup.java:61)
    at org.apache.meecrowave.Meecrowave.lambda$deployWebapp$9(Meecrowave.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.meecrowave.Meecrowave.deployWebapp(Meecrowave.java:420)
    at org.apache.meecrowave.Meecrowave.deployClasspath(Meecrowave.java:190)
    at org.talend.sdk.component.server.cli.EnhancedCli.run(EnhancedCli.java:52)
    at org.talend.sdk.component.studio.ProcessManager$2.run(ProcessManager.java:288)
```

Launch as admin and user.

Try with Java 16, Java 11 and 'OpenJDK (recommended distribution: [Zulu](https://help.talend.com/r/Msze%7E3%7ES7zxO1qT6vAXVyQ/ZOFaiTXFhb5J8VcMyXoY%7Eg))'

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between the build environment and the deployment environment. Make sure you're using the same Java version for both.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell where can i define the build environment and the deployment environment?

Comment: I found. Conclusion: 1) install JRE, 2) in TOS: change path Preference-Talend and 3) Preference-Java-Installed JRES . Thank you.

Comment: @aleksandr I had the same problem when I installed a new Java, so I think that's the answer in general - do you want to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: how did you do what is it?
I cannot remove the error for me
I have java 17 and java 8 update 301
what are TOS? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When i changed the hibernate version from 5.3.1.final to 5.4.1 final in pom.xml it resolved